# Replace string with string with javascript special chars

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace string in the entire body of html via javascript

```
var find_me='+1 123 123 123';
var replace_to='+97 654654 654';

   // not working
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('+1 123 123 123','+97 654654 654');
   // not working
```

if i try only one word without space/+ it's working
i tryed regex with \s but it didnt work as well

any help

Comment: Do you mean `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\+1 123 123 123/g, '+97 654654 654');`?

Comment: What you say is "not working" *does* work, but only for the *first* occurrence of the string. Also, it's a *really bad idea* to do `document.body.innerHTML = ...` in anything other than a simple example. It tears down all of the elements on the page, then recreates them, doing a fair bit of work and wiping out any dynamically-added event handlers. I expect there are *some* use cases, but...

Answer (score -1):

The problem been that the html contain a white space character as `&nbps;` and not normal space.

Comment: you didn't propose a solution, this seems to be a comment